# task hello-world has failed: declared workspace "output" is required but has not been bound

Tags: tekton

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Task
metadata:
  name: hello-world
spec:
  workspaces:
    - name: output
      description: folder where output goes
  steps:
    - name: hello-world1
      image: ubuntu
      command: ["/bin/bash"]
      args: ["-c", "echo Hello World 1! > $(workspaces.output.path)<200b>/message1.txt"]
    - name: hello-world2
      image: ubuntu
      script: |
        #!/usr/bin/env bash
        set -xe
        echo Hello World 2! > $(workspaces.output.path)/message2.txt
```

Comment: getting this error "task hello-world has failed: declared workspace "output" is required but has not been bound"

Comment: Please format your code . Thank you.

Comment: What is your exact problem? What have you tried? Why didn't your solutions work?

Answer (score 2):

From your error message, we can guess that the TaskRun (and PipelineRun) trying to run this task does not define a workspace to be used with your Task.

Say I would like to call your Task: I would write a Pipeline, which should include something like:

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Pipeline
metadata:
  name: hello-world
spec:
  tasks:
  - name: hello-world-task
    taskRef:
      name: hello-world
    workspaces:
    - name: output
      workspace: my-workspace

  workspaces:
  - name: my-workspace
    optional: true
```

And then, start this pipeline with the following PipelineRun:

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: PipelineRun
metadata:
  name: hello-world-0
spec:
  pipelineRef: hello-world
  workspaces:
  - name: my-workspace
    volumeClaimTemplate:
      spec:
        accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi
```

See [Tekton Pipelines Workspaces](https://tekton.dev/docs/pipelines/workspaces/) docs.